# Xml error in Android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget41"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget62"
android:layout_width="300px"
android:layout_height="292px"
android:text="Patient education is an integral part of health care delivery across medical centers in developed countries thus encouraging active patient participation and ensuring far better compliance and patient satisfaction.  It was this very dream that inspired Dr. Aniruddha and Dr. Anjali Malpani, who founded HELP in 1997, with a dream to make each and every individual in this country aware of his rights and responsibilities as a patient, of ways people could reduce the burden of health care expenses by planning and educating themselves "before" a serious medical problem could strike their family, and how doctors and patients could join hands to achieve health for all.  What started as a resource center eleven years back, with a modest collection of material on patient education, in their day care center at Om Chambers, has grown into India's only largest patient education center housing more than 11,000 authentic books on possibly every aspect of health and diseases, along with pamphlets, health care magazines, and an exhaustive audiovisual section too"
android:layout_x="10px"
android:layout_y="32px"
>
</TextView>


<Button
android:id="@+id/widget63"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Next"
android:layout_x="130px"
android:layout_y="352px"
/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I am getting this error and what's wrong in this?

> Multiple annotations found at this
>   line:
>     - No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected    for the document.
>     - Element type "TextView" must be followed by either     attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".
>     - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: You should avoid `AbsoluteLayout`, it's deprecated. You should also avoid using `px` for width and height, use `dp`.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Element type "TextView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
 - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xmlns-prefixed attribute on your root node should be the very first one the parser encounters.

Comment: What should i change in this.

Comment: Place `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` as the first attr of the `AbsoluteLayout`.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line: - Element type "TextView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) I get this now...

Comment: Your TextView's android:text property contains illegal characters, specifically two double-quotation marks. These should both be escaped to &quot;.